# Makefile rewriting files not capturing regular expressions

Tags: regex, makefile, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm using a command to rewrite files and I wanted to use it with makefile, but with makefile is not working, weird...

I exaplain all the problem, and the steps to solve it:

I have this structure:

```
/var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/<language>/<number>/01.jpg
/var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/<language>/<number>/02.jpg
/var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/<language>/<number>/03.jpg
...
```

But for new magazines, who uploads the pictures it has undesirable prefixes. `REV56_ESP-30.jpg`. I have to remove all before the number of the set magazine pictures.

So I made this command to execute to shell.

```
find /var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/ -depth -exec rename -n 's/\/var\/www\/project\/src\/assets\/img\/magazines\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+).*-/\/var\/www\/project\/src\/assets\/img\/magazines\/$1\/$2\//' {} +
```

and it works so well.

Result:

```
rename(/var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/es/88/REV88_ESP-01.jpg, /var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/es/88/01.jpg)
rename(/var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/es/88/REV88_ESP-02.jpg, /var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/es/88/02.jpg)
```

So I was happy with this, but I wanted to add this command to makefile for using it easily.

Just that:

```
magazines-rename-script-dry:
    find /var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/ -depth -exec rename -n 's/\/var\/www\/project\/src\/assets\/img\/magazines\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+).*-/\/var\/www\/project\/src\/assets\/img\/magazines\/$1\/$2\//' {} +
```

But when I run this rule:

```
root@server:/var/www/project# make magazines-rename-script-dry
find /var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/ -depth -exec rename -n 's/\/var\/www\/project\/src\/assets\/img\/magazines\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+).*-/\/var\/www\/project\/src\/assets\/img\/magazines\/\/\//' {} +
rename(/var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/es/82/REV82_ESP-26.jpg, /var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines///26.jpg)
rename(/var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/es/82/REV82_ESP-12.jpg, /var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines///12.jpg)
rename(/var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/es/82/REV82_ESP-14.jpg, /var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines///14.jpg)
rename(/var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/es/82/REV82_ESP-35.jpg, /var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines///35.jpg)
```

Why doesn't capture the number neither the language?

There is something wrong? I'm executing exactly the same line, why it has different results?

Comment: Because `$` is special to make.  If you want to escape `$` from make so it's passed to your shell script you have to double it, as `$$`.

Comment: Oh man, I know it was a silly thing... Thank you

Comment: Shell tip: in `sed` you can use ANY character as a separator between your regex's.  The standard is `/` but if your strings contain `/` you might want to pick a different character so you don't have to escape all your `/` chars.  E.g., `s|/var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/([a-z]+)/...|...|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent makefile expanding your `$`s by dollar-escaping them:

```
magazines-rename-script-dry:
    find /var/www/project/src/assets/img/magazines/ -depth -exec rename -n 's/\/var\/www\/project\/src\/assets\/img\/magazines\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+).*-/\/var\/www\/project\/src\/assets\/img\/magazines\/$$1\/$$2\//' {} +
```